# All the combinations without using itertools?

Tags: python, list

I want to know how to write an algorithm that gives me all the possible combinations of a list of numbers *with* repetition & *without* using itertools in Python.

For example: all possible combinations of the list `[1,2]`:

```
[[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,1]]
```

All possible combinations of the list `[1,2,3]`. The algorithm will then give me 27 (3<sup>3</sup>) different lists in a list.

This was my code:

```
def all_possibilities(list):
    result = [list]

    for i in list:
        new_list1 = list[:]

        for k in range(len(list)):
            new_list2 = list[:]
            new_list1[k] = i
            new_list2[k] = i
            if new_list1 != list:
                result.append(new_list1)
            if new_list2 != list:
                result.append(new_list2)

    for u in result:
        for y in result:
            if u == y and (u is y) == False:
                result.remove(y)

    return (len(result),result)
```

Comment: what specific problem are you having with the implementation?

Comment: If you are looking for pure python equivalent of `itertools.permutations` you can check the implementation of this method is [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: The concept you will need to learn is recursion.

Comment: I know the concept of recursion but I've tried writing it multiple times and I never get ALL the possible solutions.

Comment: show us what you've tried and show us how it fails.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I suggest that you read the [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) documentation, which shows what it's roughly equivalent to in pure Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `product` method which finds out the `cartesian product` of multiple lists.

```
def cartesian_product(*lists):
  result = [[]]
  for list in lists:
    result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in list]
  return result  
l = [1, 2, 3]
lst = [l for i in l]
x = cartesian_product(*lst)
for tuple in x:
   print(tuple)
```

Output

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```

Comment: "WITHOUT using itertools" was in the question

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut can you explain what happens on line 4 please? Thanks in advance

Comment: @PaulvanTieghem, basically it created a list [[1],[2],[3]] then `[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here this actually does the combinations with replacement. You can adjust the size of the combinations. I made it return a tuple because tuples are immutable and tuple operations are faster than list operations. you can however easily make it return a list of list if you want. Cheers

```
def seq_slicer(container, step=10):
    """(container)->container
    Returns slices of container in chunks of step.
    Great selecting chunks of a sequence in predetrmined slices efficiently.

    In the event where step is greater than the length of the sequence to be sliced,
    the slice taken will be the length of the sequence.

    >>> [i for i in seq_slicer(range(40), 10)]
    [range(0, 10), range(10, 20), range(20, 30), range(30, 40)]

    >>> [i for i in seq_slicer(range(41), 10)]
    [range(0, 10), range(10, 20), range(20, 30), range(30, 40), range(40, 41)]

    >>> [c for c in seq_slicer("abcdefghijklm", 3)]
    ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'm']

    >>> [c for c in seq_slicer(list("abcdefghijklm"), 3)]
    [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l'], ['m']]

    Author: Xero
    License: Apache V2
    """
    i = 0
    span = len(container)
    while i < span:
        yield container[i:i+step]
        i += step

def combinations_with_replacement(seq, num):
    """(sequence type, integer)->list
    return every possible combination of num elements from seq in lexicographic order
    >>> combinations_with_replacement([1, 2], 2)
    ((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2))


    Author: Xero
    License: Apache V2
    """
    lst = []
    _seq = tuple(seq)
    slices = [c for c in seq_slicer(_seq, num-1)]
    for elem in seq:
        for combo in [(elem,) + body for body in slices]:
            lst.append(combo)
    return tuple(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @PaulvanTieghem, your'e welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted and upvote if it works for you and you find it useful

Comment: @XeroSmith, upvote for your answer. I know the feeling when write a long and correct answer and nobody upvotes it in order to recognize the effort and time invested into answering the question.